# How to use .map file to find the space allocations of different files in embedded C

Tags: c

Is there any way to find the space allocated to various
variables and files when compiled with gcc compiler.

Comment: "files"? No. Variables, functions, possibly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410037/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-c-function, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334027/how-to-find-the-address-length-of-a-c-function-at-runtime-mingw

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the map file to find the allocations for static varibles.

If you want to sort this information based on the file containing the declaration one would have to write a program that does that, which should be possible. Same goes for code allocation.